# get string inside a div with xpath, bute before <bR>

Tags: xpath

Hello I have this HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-p-7">
    <p class="xh-highlight">
        <span id="viaBene_37002_39138" class="">Via Cassala</span>, 1<br>20143 <span id="comuneBene_37002_39138" class="">Milano</span> <span id="provinciaBene_37002_39138" class="">(MI)</span> - <span id="regioneBene_37002_39138" class="">Lombardia</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I need to get only: "Via Cassala, 1"

Now I have

```
//div[@class='col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-p-7']/p
```

to take the whole tag. The problem is that the number 1 isn't inside the span tag.
How can i take the whole string "Via Cassala 1"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `XPath`

```
concat(//span[starts-with(@id, "viaBene_")], //p[span[starts-with(@id, "viaBene_")]]//text()[2])
```

[that returns "Via Cassala, 1"](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22col-xs-7%20col-sm-6%20col-md-8%20col-p-7%22%3E%0A%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22xh-highlight%22%3E%0A%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22viaBene_37002_39138%22%20class%3D%22%22%3EVia%20Cassala%3C%2Fspan%3E%2C%201%3Cbr%3E20143%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22comuneBene_37002_39138%22%20class%3D%22%22%3EMilano%3C%2Fspan%3E%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22provinciaBene_37002_39138%22%20class%3D%22%22%3E(MI)%3C%2Fspan%3E%20-%20%3Cspan%20id%3D%22regioneBene_37002_39138%22%20class%3D%22%22%3ELombardia%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=viaBene&extract=concat(%2F%2Fspan[starts-with(%40id%2C%20%22viaBene_%22)]%2C%20%2F%2Fp%2F%2Ftext()[2])&=concat(%2F%2Fspan[starts-with(%40id%2C%20%22viaBene_%22)]%2C%20%2F%2Fp%2F%2Ftext()[2])&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xquery1)

Comment: Thank you but I made an errore The tag xh-hilight nwas inserted by the chrome estension tool. and concat(//span[starts-with(@id, "viaBene_")], //p//text()[2]) doesn't work

Comment: I've removed class name based predicate. Try updated answer

Comment: The correct html is <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-p-7">
    <p>
        <span id="viaBene_37002_39138" class="">Via Cassala</span>, 1<br>20143 <span id="comuneBene_37002_39138" class="">Milano</span> <span id="provinciaBene_37002_39138" class="">(MI)</span> - <span id="regioneBene_37002_39138" class="">Lombardia</span>
    </p>
</div> but doesn't work

Comment: It still should work with provided `HTML` sample. Can you share exception log? And also specify `XPath` version you should use. Is it `1.0`?

Comment: it returns "Via Cassala20143". I'm usign xpath extension for chrome to check

Comment: There might be some issues with white-spaces. Try to replace `text()[2]` with `text()[1]`